# AYUDA CON AJAX QUE PRESENTA RESULTADOS

Tags: php, html, ajax, web, diseño

Estimados por favor su ayuda, tengo un ajax que toma la información de un json que manda un php y me presenta el html como tablas, cada tabla tiene un botón nuevo que necesito envíe la variable cedula y me traiga nuevo json desde php pero al dar click en el botón me refresca la página y no hace lo que por el momento le puse que me muestre un mensaje en el log, como pueden ver el tema de que me genere las tablas y me consulte al php según el tipo de dato lo tengo controlado, sin embargo el llamar una nueva acción con el botón btn-participaciones se me complica

gracias de antemano su ayuda así está el código ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
console.log("avanzamos");  
$('#userdata').html("");       
$('#btn-buscar').click(function(e){
$('#userdata').html("");
$('#container').html("");
$('#container1').html('<table class="tablaespere"><tr><td class=error align=center><img  height="300" 
width= "300"align = "center" src="loader.gif" alt="loading" />POR FAVOR ESPERE!!!</td></tr> 
</table>');
e.preventDefault();
var value=$.trim($("#search").val());
if(value.length==0){
  $('#userdata').html("");
  $('#container1').html('<table class="tablavacio"><tr><td class=error align=center>POR FAVOR INGRESE 
UN DATO!!!</td></tr></table>');

}else{
      if($.isNumeric($('#search').val())) {
      var url = 'datos2.php';
      let search = $('#search').val();
      console.log(search);
      $.ajax({                        
      type: 'POST',                 
      url: url,                     
      data: {search}, 
      success: function(response)             
     {
      console.log(response);
       let datos = JSON.parse(response);
       let template = '';
       $('#container1').html("") 
      $('#userdata > tbody').empty();
        datos.forEach(elements =>{
        var $total = `Se encontro ${datos.length} registros`;
        var img =`${elements.Foto}`;
        var img1 = img.replace("\/","/");

        template += 
        ` 
        <div>
        <table class=tabladatos>          
        <tr><td rowspan=9  width=400 bgcolor=white border align=center><img width=350 height=400 
   src='data:image/jpeg;base64,${img1}'></td>
        </td>
        <td class=titulos>NOMBRE</td><td class = resultados>${elements.Nombre}</td></tr>
        <tr><td class=titulos>COMET ID</td><td class = resultados>${elements.Comet}</td></tr>
        <tr><td class=titulos>FECHA DE NACIMIENTO</td><td class = resultados>${elements.Fecha}</td> 
</tr>
        <tr><td class=titulos>EDAD</td><td class = resultados>${elements.Edad}</td></tr>
        <tr><td class=titulos>NACIONALIDAD</td><td class = resultados>${elements.Nacionalidad}</td> 
</tr>
        <tr><td class=titulos>POSICION</td><td class = resultados>${elements.Posicion}</td></tr>
        <tr><td class=titulos>TIPO DE SANGRE</td><td class = resultados>${elements.Sangre}</td></tr>
        <tr><td class=titulos>FUNCION</td><td class = resultados>${elements.Funcion}</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan=2 align=center>
        <form>
        <input type=hidden id=id name=id value=${elements.Cedula}>
        <button id = "btn-participaciones" class="boton" onmouseover=this.style.background='#ff4040',this.style.color='white' onmouseout=this.style.background='#252D54',this.style.color='white' type="submit">PARTICIPACIONES</button></td></tr>
        </form>
        </table>
        <div class=separador>
        </div>
        </div>
        `           
        $('#container1').html(template);
        $('#container').html($total);
        $('#search').html("");                                                     
         });
        } //final del success
      })
  } //final del ifnumeric
  else{
    var url = 'datos2.php';
  let search = $('#search').val();
  console.log(search);
   $.ajax({                        
     type: 'POST',                 
     url: url,                     
     data: {search}, 
      success: function(response)             
     {
      $("#tabladatos").paginationTdA({
        elemPerPage: 45
        });
      $('#container1').html("") 
      //console.log(response);
      let datos = JSON.parse(response); 
      let template = '';
      console.log(datos);
       $('#userdata > tbody').empty();

       datos.forEach(elements =>{
        var $total = `Se encontro ${datos.length} registros`;
        var img =`${elements.Foto}`;
        var img1 = img.replace("\/","/");

        template += 
        `
        <div>
        <table class=tabladatos> 
        <tr><td rowspan=9  width=400 bgcolor=white border align=center><img width=350 height=400 src='data:image/jpeg;base64,${img1}'></td>
        </td>
        <td class=titulos>NOMBRE</td><td class = resultados>${elements.Nombre}</td></tr>
        <tr><td class=titulos>COMET ID</td><td class = resultados>${elements.Comet}</td></tr>
        <tr><td class=titulos>FECHA DE NACIMIENTO</td><td class = resultados>${elements.Fecha}</td></tr>
        <tr><td class=titulos>EDAD</td><td class = resultados>${elements.Edad}</td></tr>
        <tr><td class=titulos>NACIONALIDAD</td><td class = resultados>${elements.Nacionalidad}</td></tr>
        <tr><td class=titulos>POSICION</td><td class = resultados>${elements.Posicion}</td></tr>
        <tr><td class=titulos>TIPO DE SANGRE</td><td class = resultados>${elements.Sangre}</td></tr>
        <tr><td class=titulos>FUNCION</td><td class = resultados>${elements.Funcion}</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan=2 align=center>
        <form  action="" method="">
        <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="${elements.Cedula}">
        <button id = "btn-participaciones" class="boton" onmouseover=this.style.background='#ff4040',this.style.color='white' onmouseout=this.style.background='#252D54',this.style.color='white' type="submit">PARTICIPACIONES</button></td></tr>
        </form>
        </table>
        <div class=separador>
        </div>
        </div>
        `  

        $('#container1').html(template);
        $('#container').html($total);
        $('#search').html("");                                                     
         });

       }
    });
  }//finaliza condicion para buscar por nombres

}
 })//finaliza la funcion del boton buscar


 $('#btn-participaciones').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();


  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero, tu petición debe ser de tipo GET. Es necesario saber la diferencia según lo requerido. Por otro lado, puedes intentar añadiendo un "eventListener" a tu botón.

```
btn.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Codigo AJAX
});
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, las peticiones son post porque envían una variable al php que procesa la comunicación con el servidor y devuelve un json al ajax, voy a probar la del eventListener.